# The generalised Catalan Numbers and Borel's Triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I am currently reading "Counting with Borel’s Triangle" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01597), and am very confused on a stated formula.

We know:

$C_{n,k}=\frac{n-k+1}{n+1}{n+k \choose n}$

$C(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n}x^{n}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$

$C(t,x)=\sum_{n,k}C_{n,k}t^kx^n =\frac{C(tx)}{1-xC(tx)}$

$C(2,i)=\sum_{k}C_{i-1,k}2^k$

These I can completely understand the derivation of.

However, I cannot under formula (7):

$\sum_{i\geq0}C(2,i)x^i=\frac{1+2xC(2x)}{1+x}=\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}=\frac{4}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}$

How are these equal? Clearly, the last equals holds, but how does the first or second?

To start, I assume we have:

$\sum_{i\geq0}C(2,i)x^i=\sum_{i\geq0}\sum_{k}C_{i-1,k}2^kx^i$

I then assume we reindex:

$\sum_{i\geq0}\sum_{k}C_{i-1,k}2^kx^i=\sum_{n+1\geq0}\sum_{k}C_{n,k}2^kx^{n+1}$

Then we can remove a factor of $x$:

$\sum_{n+1\geq0}\sum_{k}C_{n,k}2^kx^{n+1}=x\sum_{n+1\geq0}\sum_{k}C_{n,k}2^kx^{n}$

But now I am stuck. I feel like I've gone down a completely wrong path?

Comment: Interesting paper. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

We show the validity of the equality chain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i\geq0}C(2;i)x^i=\frac{1+2xC(2x)}{1+x}=\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}=\frac{4}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}
\end{align*}
with $$C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$  the generating  function  of   the   *[Catalan  numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof)* and the generalized Catalan numbers $C(2;i)$ stored in OEIS as *[A064062](https://oeis.org/A064062)*.

> **First part:** $\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}=\frac{4}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}$
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}}&=\frac{1}{1-x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-8x}}{4x}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{4}{4-(1-\sqrt{1-8x})}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{4}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Second  part:** $\frac{1+2xC(2x)}{1+x}=\frac{4}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}$
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1+2xC(2x)}{1+x}}&=\frac{1}{1+x}\left(1+2x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-8x}}{4x}\right)\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{1+x}\left(1+\frac{1-\sqrt{1-8x}}{2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2(1+x)}\left(3-\sqrt{1-8x}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2(1+x)}\cdot\frac{9-(1-8x)}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{4}{3+\sqrt{1-8x}}}
> \end{align*}

For the next part it is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

We start by inspecting $C(2;i)=\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}C_{i-1,k}2^k$ and looking at the relationship with the bivariate generating function

\begin{align*}
C(t;x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^nC_{n,k}t^kx^k=\frac{C(tx)}{1-xC(tx)}.
\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> **Third part:** $\sum_{i\geq0}C(2;i)x^i=\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}$
>
> We obtain for $i\geq 1$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{C(2;i)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}C_{i-1,k}2^k\\
> &=[x^{i-1}]\frac{C(2x)}{1-xC(2x)}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^i]\frac{xC(2x)}{1-xC(2x)}\\
> &=[x^i]\left(\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}-1\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[x^i]\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> With $C(2;0)=1$ we finally obtain from (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}C(2;i)x^i}&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty[u^i]\frac{1}{1-uC(2u)}x^i\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-xC(2x)}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we evaluate (1) at $t=2$.
- In (4) we use the *substitution rule*
  \begin{align*}
  A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty [u^n]A(u) x^n
  \end{align*}